# Old password field is not shown in th browsable api django rest auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

I'm using the Django rest framework with Django rest auth. When I access rest-auth/password/change it prompts me to enter new password 1 and new password 2. But in the serializer, there's a field for old password also. But I can't see it in the browsable API window. What is the reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the problem. There's a boolean value to change the visibility of fields.